# Ignore dependency with buildout

Tags: python, dependency-management, buildout, egg

Here is my `buildout.cfg`:

```
[buildout]
extends = versions.cfg
eggs = package1
       package2
parts = installeggs

[installeggs]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

And my `versions.cfg`:

```
[versions]
package1 = 1.0
package2 = 2.0
```

Unfortunately, `package2`'s version requires another version of `package1`.

```
Error: The requirement ('package1>=2.0') is not allowed by your [versions] constraint (1.0)
```

Is there an option I'm not aware of to install this version of `package1` anyway? Something like the `--no-deps` option of pip for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a workaround consisting in running `pip install --no-deps`, but it forced me to declare another part.

```
[buildout]
extends = versions.cfg
eggs = package1
#      package2
parts = installeggs
        forceinstall

[installeggs]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[forceinstall]
recipe = collective.recipe.cmd
on_install = true
cmds = ${buildout:directory}/bin/pip install --no-deps package2==2.0
```